# MySQL connector query

Tags: python, mysql-connector

So I am trying to execute this query but there is definitely a syntax error I have which I wasn't able to figure out.
If someone could help me that would be greatly appreciated. :)

```py
query = """INSERT IGNORE INTO %s(id, title, body_text, username,time_created,num_of_comments, subreddit, full_link, upvote_ratio) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
mycursor.execute(query, (post_table_name, tuple1),)
```

The current runtime error is
`result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(*params) _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type tuple cannot be converted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table names and field names cannot use substitution.  Assuming you're on Python 3, you can use an 'f' string:

```
query = f"""INSERT IGNORE INTO {post_table_name} (id, title, body_text, username,time_created,num_of_comments, subreddit, full_link, upvote_ratio) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

mycursor.execute(query, tuple1)
```